# Is there a way to enable Android debugging by PC?

Tags: adb, usb-debugging, locked-out

I'm trying to turn on debugging on my Samsung Galaxy J5 so I can use `adb shell rm /data/system/gesture/.key` and unlock my phone screen so I don't have to reset it and lose all its data (but it's locked with my PIN). For that, I need to know how to debug it just by the Command Prompt.

Is there a way to enable Android debugging by PC?

Comment: You cannot. adb daemon can be only started by android OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point pursuing this course of action. Deleting any file under `/data/system` requires root access. Android doesn't provide any way to users to access powers of root. A user has to resort to system hacking (called as rooting the device) to get root access. And in that process, most of the time the user data is wiped in the process.

In short, even if you somehow manage to enable and authorize USB debugging the problem of "no-root-access" would stonewall you. And if you try to root the device, you will end up deleting all of your data -- the very thing you want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to try this with recovery mode.
Download a custom recovery like ClockWorkMode or TWRP for your device. Then enter in recovery mode by holding Vol Up and pressing power. The recovery will give you root access with no need to grant permission.

Comment: Doesn't flashing a custom recovery need an unlocked bootloader, and that also mean wiping the data first?

Comment: I'm sorry Andrew, you are right, it does require OEM unlock to boot on TWRP recovery mode. I think Firelord's analysis is correct. It cannot be done.